# regex repetition aa,bb,cc

Tags: regex, ruby

I expected the following to work (and it does):

```
x = '"aa","bb","cc"'

x =~ /\A(".*?",){2}".*?"\Z/
#=> 0
```

...but I did not expect the following two to work (and don't want them to work). I purposely used `?` to make `.*` non-greedy:

```
x =~ /\A(".*?",){0}".*?"\Z/
#=> 0 

x =~ /\A(".*?",){1}".*?"\Z/
#=> 0
```

I expect: beginning of line (`\A`), followed by `"aa",`, followed by `"bb",` (that's two matches now, i.e. `{2}`), and then `"cc"`, and the end of line `\Z`.

I understand *why* they are working, but I want to understand how to achieve what I want...

I want it to *fail* on the last two examples above (but it doesn't). Put another way, I want the following to fail:

```
x = '"aa","bb","cc","dd"'

x =~ /\A(".*?",){2}".*?"\Z/
#=> 0
```

It should see: `\A`, `"aa"`, `"bb"`, `"cc"` and then FAIL on the subsequent `,` (the fact that it was not `\Z`).

Comment: The lazy quantifier `?` merely tells the regex engine to match as little as possible and then go on. However, the smallest string between `"aa","bb","` and `"\Z` is `cc","dd`, i.e. the whole remaining part. It can't match anything less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `.` is too generic, and that even a non-greedy `.*?` will match `,` or `"`:

```
'"aa","bb","cc"'.match(/\A(".*?",){1}(".*?")\Z/).captures
#=> ["\"aa\",", "\"bb\",\"cc\""]
```

Also, there is no difference between a greedy and a non-greedy match if they both need to continue until the end of the string. `/.*\Z/` is the same as `/.*?\Z/`.

You cannot remove `\Z` so you could replace `.` with `[^"]` to avoid matching `"`.

```
three = '"aa","bb","cc"'
four = '"aa","bb","cc","dd"'

pattern = /\A("[^"]*",){2}"[^"]*"\Z/

(three =~ pattern) && (four !~ pattern)
#=> true
```

[image: regex on debuggex]

If the regex becomes too unreadable, an alternative would be to try to parse your text as a JSON array:

```
require 'json'
three = '"aa","bb","cc"'
four = '"aa","bb","cc","dd"'

def has_n_strings?(text, n)
  words = JSON.parse("[#{text}]")
  words.all?(String) && words.size == n
end

puts has_n_strings?(three, 3)
# true
puts has_n_strings?(three, 4)
# false
puts has_n_strings?(four, 4)
# true
puts has_n_strings?(four, 3)
# false
```

Comment: Please elaborate your first sentence. What does "too generic" mean? Why is that a problem? You have not answered the question. You have proposed a work-around, but the question did not ask for that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. Is it better now?

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah, I didn't notice. OP's question was updated before I got here.

Comment: I get it! I finally get it! Many thanks! I see now that `{n}` following a capture group was just a smoke-screen. Let's take a small example. `"abb"[/\A(.*?)b/] #=> "ab"; $1 #=> "a"`. We are to match all characters from the beginning of the string lazily. Does "lazily" mean "until the next character is a 'b'"? That explanation is consistent with the result. Now let's add an end anchor: `"abb"[/\A(.*?)b\z/] #=> "abb"; $1 #=> "ab"`...

Comment: ...We see that `"ab"` was matched in the capture group, showing that the answer to my earlier question is "no", that `.*?` means "match as few characters as needed to achieve a match". This is exactly what @Stefan said in his comment, but it took me awhile to process it. Incidentally, I see that, contrary to what I said in my first comment, the OP did want an alternative way of achieving the result. Good job.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks for the comments. Adding `/\Z/` negates any benefit the non-greedy match could have. It needs to match until the end of string anyway.

Comment: Yes, but in other circumstances, with `\Z`, the lazy match can still make a difference: `"abbb"[/(.*?)(.*?)b\Z/] #=> "abbb"; $1 => ""; $2 #=> "abb"`, whereas `"abbb"[/(.*)(.*?)b\Z/] #=> "abbb"; $1 #=> "abb"; $2 #=> ""`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I was talking about the last match, which needs to continue until the end of the string anyway. I can surely make a difference if there's something between the non-greedy match and the end of the string.

Comment: Hence my qualifier.

Comment: That's really awesome. Thank you. I can hardly believe that I didn't think of `[^,"]+`. By the way, `[^"]+` works better for me, as sometimes there can actually be commas inside the strings... e.g. `"aa"` can be `"a,a"`. So: `pattern = /\A("[^"]+",){2}"[^"]+"\Z/` and `(three =~ pattern) && (four !~ pattern)` still gives `true` when `three='"a,a","b,b","c,c"'`, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't want to bug you, but the more I work with it and think about it, the more I realize that *the answer* should be `pattern = /\A("[^"]*",){2}"[^"]*"\Z/`, because there is no need to involve the comma, and the `*` permits empty strings, which is more in line with the original `.*?` (which allows empty strings). This means two changes to the current answer: The first is to remove the comma from `[^,"]+` in both occurrences, and the second is to replace the `+` with `*` also in both occurrences. Again, thank you for your answer. I could not have gotten here without you. I am grateful.